# Test problem in near protocole template app WASM file

Tags: testing, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

I simply created an app with npx create-near-app@latest

When i run the following command :

npm run build && npm run test

I have the following error :

`Debugger attached.
⚠ The timeout option has been disabled to help with debugging.

Uncaught exception in ../build/hello_near.wasm

/Users/sidox/dev/web3/hello-near/build/hello_near.wasm:1

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

› SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
› require.extensions. (node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1608:43)

✘ ../build/hello_near.wasm exited with a non-zero exit code: 1
─

1 uncaught exception
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...`

while in the doc the result would be :

`# Expected:

## returns the default greeting ✅

## changes the greeting ✅`